# For all $R$-modules $N$, $R\otimes_R N\cong N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Why is this so? This statement is from Aluffi's book *Algebra: Chapter 0* and seemingly so trivial that it deserves no proof.

So working with the universal property of tensor products, how exactly does every $R$-bilinear map $R\times N\longrightarrow P$ factor through $N$? Here $P$ is another $R$-module.

The map $R\times N\overset{\otimes}\longrightarrow N$ is given as $\otimes(r,n)=rn$.

Comment: I'm stuck on this too. Seems horribly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, any $R$ bilinear map $f:R \times N \to M$ is really a linear map from $N$ to $M$ in disguise, for if $g$ is a linear map from $N$ to $M$, then we may define $f$ by letting $f(1,n) = g(n)$, extended to a unique bilinear extension. The details are then trivial.

Let $f: R \times N \to M$ be a bilinear map. Given your projection map $(r,n) \mapsto rn$, if we have a factor map $g: N \to M$, then we must define

$$ g(rn) = f(r,n) $$

Certainly this defines $g$ for all $n \in N$, for $n = 1n$. Suppose $rn = r'n'$. Then, since $f$ is bilinear,

$$ f(r,n) = rf(1,n) = f(1,rn) = f(1,r'n') = r'f(1,n') = f(r',n') $$

So $g$ is well defined. That $g$ is a linear map follows because

$$ g(rn) = f(r,n) = rf(1,n) = rg(n)$$
$$ g(n + m) = f(1, n + m) = f(1, n) + f(1,m) = g(n) + g(m) $$

and $g$ is obviously a unique factor, and thus $N$ is a tensor product over $R$ for $R$ and $N$.

Comment: How do I extend your proof to the multilinear case, i.e. $R^{\oplus n}\times M \cong M^{\oplus n}$? I assume the projection map $(r_1,...,r_n,m)\mapsto (r_1m,...,r_nm)$. How would I prove well-definedness here? I tried to do it analogously to your argument above but I fail to see why $(\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m=(\prod_{i=1}^nr'_i)m'$, or is the projection wrong?

Comment: To check a function is well defined, we assume that

$$ (\prod_{i = 1}^n r_i) m = (\prod_{i = 1}^n r_i') m' $$

and then show that the value of $(r_1, \dots, r_n, m)$ is the same as the value of $(r_1', \dots, r_n', m')$ under a multilinear map $f$. But this follows exactly as in the multilinear case, for

$$ f(r_1, \dots, r_n, m) = (\prod r_i) f(1, \dots, 1, m) = f(1, \dots, 1, (\prod r_i) m) $$

So unless I'm mistaken, isn't the $n$-fold tensor product $R \otimes R \otimes \dots \otimes R \otimes M$ isomorphic to $M$ again (This follows by induction as well)?

Answer (score 2):

The set of $R$-bilinear maps $f: R\times N\to P$ is in natural bijection with the set of $R$-linear maps $g:N\to P$. The correspondence is obtained by setting $f(r,n) = g(rn)$.